# Forecast number of products that can be made given bill of materials

Tags: windows-7, inventory

I'm looking for an inventory management solution to let us know how many products we can make given the number of raw materials we have and how many more we need of the raw materials to make a given amount products, simple maths.

I'm trying out **inFlow Inventory** system and **oDoo** at the moment, none have these features without first making and completing the work order then going into negative products and calculating from here.

Budget is up to $1500, looking for something accessible by windows OS. Preferably server based that can be multi-user. 4-5 users.

Comment: Welcome aboard. We would love to help you, but you need to give us some help too. Which operating system? Should it be free (use the "gratis" tag), or do you have a budget? And, can you tell us what you mean by "structured"? Please read [ask]. The more we know about what you want, the better a match we can find for you.